# python class __dict__ usage for cloning object attributes

Tags: python, class, object, copy

*EDIT*
Clarification: While I do appreciate the corrections/suggestions for deep `copy` that are already posted, this question is mainly about usage of `__dict__` method of class, and whether cloning object attrs using **init** this way is okay.

Is there any issue with this usage of init for copying object attrs, better way to achieve this?

```
class CopyClass(obj):
    def __init__(self, obj1):
        super().__init__()
        self.__dict__ = obj1.__dict__.copy()

obj2 = CopyClass(obj1)
```

Comment: `copy` does not make a "deep" copy, you simply copy the references.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  `import copy; copy.deepcopy(..)` ?

Comment: oh, this is just posted as an answer already

Comment: Of course, you may not need a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

```py
from copy import deepcopy

obj = Foo()  # Foo is some random class
obj_copy = deepcopy(obj)
```